# Convert binary data to signed integer

Tags: python

I read a binary file and get an array with characters. When converting two bytes to an integer I do `256*ord(p1) + ord(p0)`. It works fine for positive integers but when I get a negative number it doesn't work. I know there is something with the first bit in the most significant byte but with no success.

I also understand there is something called `struct` and after reading I ended up with the following code

```
import struct

p1 = chr(231)
p0 = chr(174)

a = struct.unpack('h',p0+p1)

print str(a)
```

`a` becomes -6226 and if I swap `p0` and `p1` I get -20761.

`a` should have been -2

Answer (score 2):

-2 is not correct for the values you have specified, and byte order matters.  `struct` uses `>` for big-endian (most-significant byte first) and `<` for little-endian (least-significant byte first):

```
>>> import struct
>>> struct.pack('>h',-2)
'\xff\xfe'
>>> struct.pack('<h',-2)
'\xfe\xff'
>>> p1=chr(254) # 0xFE
>>> p0=chr(255) # 0xFF
>>> struct.unpack('<h',p1+p0)[0]
-2
>>> struct.unpack('>h',p0+p1)[0]
-2
```

Answer (score 1):

Generally, when using struct, your format string should start with one of the [alignment specifiers](http://docs.python.org/library/struct.html#byte-order-size-and-alignment). The default, native one differs from machine to machine.

Therefore, the correct result is

```
>>> struct.unpack('!h',p0+p1)[0]
-20761
```

The representation of -2 in big [endian](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/484764/endianness-theory-and-concept) is:

```
1111 1111 1111 1110 # binary
  255        254    # decimal bytes
  f   f    f    e   # hexadecimal bytes
```

You can easily verify that by adding two, which results in 0.

Answer (score 0):

With the first method (`256*ord(p1) + ord(p0)`), you could check to see if the first bit is 1 with `if p1 & 0x80 > 0`. If so then you'd use `p1 & 0x7f` instead of `p1` and then negate the end result.

Answer (score 0):

Your original equation will work fine if you use masking to take off the extra `1` bits in a negative number:

```
256*(ord(p0) & 0xff) + (ord(p1) & 0xff)
```

**Edit:** I think I might have misunderstood your question. You're trying to convert two positive byte values into a negative integer? This should work:

```
a = 256*ord(p0) + ord(p1)
if a > 32767: # 0x7fff
    a -= 65536 # 0x10000
```

Comment: Since those are already 8-bit quantities, masking off the lower 8-bits doesn't do anything.

Comment: To mask the sign bit, you would use `& 0x7F`, no?

Comment: @kindall, the original question speaks of negative numbers. Negative numbers are sign-extended so the upper bits contain `1` instead of `0`, thus masking them becomes necessary. I'm still not quite sure how `ord` returns a negative number though.

Comment: @Colt45, if you use `& 0x7f` you will lose the 8th bit. You don't want to remove the sign bit, you want to remove its extensions to the left.

Comment: 'ord()' doesn't return a negative number -- the two-byte numbers he's trying to decode are negative.

Answer (score 0):

For the record, you can do it without `struct`. Your original equation can be used, but if the result is greater than 32767, subtract 65536. (Or if the high-order byte is greater than 127, which is the same thing.) Look up two's complement, which is how all modern computers represent negative integers.

```
p1 = chr(231)
p0 = chr(174)

a = 256 * ord(p1) + ord(p0) - (65536 if ord(p1) > 127 else 0)
```

This gets you the correct answer of -6226. (The correct answer *is not -2.*)

Answer (score 0):

If you are converting values from a file that is large, use the [array](http://docs.python.org/library/array.html) module.

For a file, know that it is the endianess of the file format that matters. Not the endianess of the machine that either wrote it or is reading it.

Alex Martelli, of course, has [the definitive answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1400012/endianness-of-integers-in-python).