# C# int to byte[]

Tags: c#, .net, bit-manipulation, nfs

I need to convert an `int` to a `byte[]` one way of doing it is to use `BitConverter.GetBytes()`. But im unsure if that matches the following specification:

> An XDR signed integer is a 32-bit datum that encodes an integer in
>      the range [-2147483648,2147483647].  The integer is represented in
>      two's complement notation.  The most and least significant bytes are
>      0 and 3, respectively.  Integers are declared as follows:

Source: `RFC1014 3.2`

How could i do a int to byte transformation that would satisfy the above specification?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In .NET Core 2.1+ and .NET 5+ you can use [`BinaryPrimitives.WriteInt32BigEndian()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.buffers.binary.binaryprimitives.writeint32bigendian) like this:

```
int intVal = ...;
byte[] bytes = new byte[4];
BinaryPrimitives.WriteInt32BigEndian(bytes, intVal);
```

- The conversion is done in one line.
- It is a built in function.
- It does not depend on the endianness of the computer.

Answer (score 270):

The RFC is just trying to say that a signed integer is a normal 4-byte integer with bytes ordered in a big-endian way.

Now, you are most probably working on a little-endian machine and `BitConverter.GetBytes()` will give you the `byte[]` reversed. So you could try:

```
int intValue;
byte[] intBytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(intValue);
Array.Reverse(intBytes);
byte[] result = intBytes;
```

For the code to be most portable, however, you can do it like this:

```
int intValue;
byte[] intBytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(intValue);
if (BitConverter.IsLittleEndian)
    Array.Reverse(intBytes);
byte[] result = intBytes;
```

Comment: Or use ToArray. byte[] result = BitConverter.GetBytes(intValue).Reverse().ToArray();

Comment: why the last line `byte[] result = intBytes;` ? isn't `intBytes` already the array you want?

Comment: @derHugo That's correct, `result` is redundant in this code piece. However, I felt that it was more pedagogical to explicitly show the reader what the result was than assuming that they can figure out that the result is contained in some variable named `intBytes`.  Besides, doing the assignment is cheap since it does not copy the memory nor allocate new memory, it just adds a new name to the already allocated array. So why not do it?

Answer (score 56):

Here's another way to do it: as we all know 1x byte = 8x bits and also, a "regular" integer (int32) contains 32 bits (4 bytes). We can use the >> operator to shift bits right (>> operator does not change value.)

```
int intValue = 566;

byte[] bytes = new byte[4];

bytes[0] = (byte)(intValue >> 24);
bytes[1] = (byte)(intValue >> 16);
bytes[2] = (byte)(intValue >> 8);
bytes[3] = (byte)intValue;

Console.WriteLine("{0} breaks down to : {1} {2} {3} {4}",
    intValue, bytes[0], bytes[1], bytes[2], bytes[3]);
```

Comment: The array initializer and the xor (^) and `& 0xFF` bits are unnecessary.

Comment: It's big-endian, so MSB is stored first, so you should inverse your indices.

Comment: Can we add an example of going the opposite way? (bytes back to integer)

Comment: I use this because of performance. If I don't care about this _small_ difference, I will go for the accepted answer.

Comment: You should wrap that code in an `unchecked` block. Currently it only works if integer overflow checking is disabled in the compiler settings.

Answer (score 29):

`BitConverter.GetBytes(int)` almost does what you want, except the endianness is wrong.

You can use the [IPAddress.HostToNetwork](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/653kcke1.aspx) method to swap the bytes within the the integer value before using `BitConverter.GetBytes` or use Jon Skeet's [EndianBitConverter class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217980/c-little-endian-or-big-endian/217993#217993). Both methods do the right thing(tm) regarding portability.

```
int value;
byte[] bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(IPAddress.HostToNetworkOrder(value));
```

Answer (score 21):

The other way is to use [BinaryPrimitives](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.buffers.binary.binaryprimitives?view=netcore-3.1) like so

`byte[] intBytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(123);
 int actual = BinaryPrimitives.ReadInt32LittleEndian(intBytes);`

Comment: This should be top answer, but consider adding: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.bitconverter.islittleendian?view=net-5.0

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. But beware - it's available starting from .NET 5.0 and .NET Core 2.1.

Comment: whats with the '123'?

Comment: Just an example - "int actual" should end up as 123.

Answer (score 7):

Why all this code in the samples above...

A struct with explicit layout acts both ways and has no performance hit.

Update: Since there's a question on how to deal with endianness I added an interface that illustrates how to abstract that. Another implementing struct can deal with the opposite case

```
public interface IIntToByte
{
    Int32 Int { get; set;}

    byte B0 { get; }
    byte B1 { get; }
    byte B2 { get; }
    byte B3 { get; }
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
public struct IntToByteLE : UserQuery.IIntToByte
{
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public Int32 IntVal;

    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public byte b0;
    [FieldOffset(1)]
    public byte b1;
    [FieldOffset(2)]
    public byte b2;
    [FieldOffset(3)]
    public byte b3;

    public Int32 Int {
        get{ return IntVal; }
        set{ IntVal = value;}
    }

    public byte B0 => b0;
    public byte B1 => b1;
    public byte B2 => b2;
    public byte B3 => b3; 
}
```

Comment: How would you use this? and secondly would you get the same result even is you run this on 'big-endian' and on 'little-endian'.

Comment: @Peter here's an update. It should still perform better than shifts

Comment: yup. Basically a c++ union implemented as c# structs. This is super-fast and is good for packing and unpacking all kinds of things that don't fit nicely into the bitconverter/endian problem solutions. IIRC, NAudio uses this approach to very good effect.

Comment: This is the best answer and it's kinda sad that this isn't the top but just tells you something about the state of programming in 2019

Answer (score 3):

When I look at this description, I have a feeling, that this xdr integer is just a big-endian "standard" integer, but it's expressed in the most obfuscated way. [Two's complement notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement) is better know as U2, and it's what we are using on today's processors. The byte order indicates that it's a [big-endian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) notation.
So, answering your question, you should inverse elements in your array (0 <--> 3, 1 <-->2), as they are encoded in little-endian. Just to make sure, you should first check `BitConverter.IsLittleEndian` to see on what machine you are running.

Answer (score 2):

If you want more general information about various methods of representing numbers including Two's Complement have a look at:

[Two's Complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement) and [Signed Number Representation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_number_representations) on Wikipedia

Answer (score 0):

````
using static System.Console;

namespace IntToBits
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                string s = Console.ReadLine();
                Clear();
                uint i;
                bool b = UInt32.TryParse(s, out i);
                if (b) IntPrinter(i);
            }
        }

        static void IntPrinter(uint i)
        {
            int[] iarr = new int [32];
            Write("[");
            for (int j = 0; j < 32; j++)
            {
                uint tmp = i & (uint)Math.Pow(2, j);

                iarr[j] = (int)(tmp >> j);
            }
            for (int j = 32; j > 0; j--)
            {
                if(j%8==0 && j != 32)Write("|");
                if(j%4==0 && j%8 !=0) Write("'");
                Write(iarr[j-1]);
            }
            WriteLine("]");
        }
    }
}```
````

Answer (score -2):

```
byte[] Take_Byte_Arr_From_Int(Int64 Source_Num)
{
   Int64 Int64_Num = Source_Num;
   byte Byte_Num;
   byte[] Byte_Arr = new byte[8];
   for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
   {
      if (Source_Num > 255)
      {
         Int64_Num = Source_Num / 256;
         Byte_Num = (byte)(Source_Num - Int64_Num * 256);
      }
      else
      {
         Byte_Num = (byte)Int64_Num;
         Int64_Num = 0;
      }
      Byte_Arr[i] = Byte_Num;
      Source_Num = Int64_Num;
   }
   return (Byte_Arr);
}
```

Comment: please add more explanation

Comment: Thanks for the answer, why did you choose to write a new implementation instead of using the https://stackoverflow.com/a/1318948/58553 ? (are there any pro or cons with your solution)

Comment: In case when project need to be developed with not only one language, it can be useful realize code similarity between languages in situation when identical ideas must be implemented. This way may help with mistakes catching. Sure using ‘c#’ function ‘BitConverter.GetBytes’ with ‘Endian’ checking that all what needed in most cases. And more, in some situation may happened use conversion not only to Int32(4 bytes) or Int64(8 bytes) but to other number of bytes. Thanks.

Comment: This isn't really universally usable at all... it always returns an 8-byte array, which brings a lot of extra work with input values that aren't 64-bit ints. I'd logically want a 2-byte array when converting an `Int16`.