# Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.Byte[]'

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I saved image into sql data base of datat type image(Binary) and its successfully saved .. now i need to retrive it in my datalist .. after i bound it into my datalist in my markup .. i got this error

**Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.Byte[]'.**

here is my behind code

```
 if (!(this.IsPostBack))
    {
        // For News DataList
        prepareConnection();
        _command.CommandText = "select top 5 * from News ORDER BY id DESC";

        _adp = new SqlDataAdapter();
        _tbl = new System.Data.DataTable();
        _adp.SelectCommand = _command;
        _adp.Fill(_tbl);
        SqlDataReader DataReader = _command.ExecuteReader();
        DataReader.Read();
        Response.BinaryWrite((byte[])DataReader[0]);
        DataReader.Close();
        dlNews.DataSource = _tbl;
        dlNews.DataBind();
    }


  protected void prepareConnection()
{
    _connection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=******\localhost;Initial Catalog=******;User ID=sa;Password=****");
    _connection.Open();
    _command = new SqlCommand();
    _command.Connection = _connection;

}
```

and here is DataList markup :

```
<asp:DataList ID="dlNews" runat="server">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <a href='./NewsView.aspx?ID=<%#Eval("ID") %>' style="text-decoration: none;">
                            <div id="123">
                                <a href='NewsView.aspx?ID=<%#Eval("ID") %>' style="text-decoration: none;">
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblTitle" runat="server" Style="font-size: 15px; font-weight: bold;
                                        line-height: 20px;" Text='<%# Eval("Title").ToString().Length>70 ? (Eval("Title") as string).Substring(0,70) : Eval("Title") %>'></asp:Label>
                                </a>
                                <div id="image" style="clear: both; float: right; margin: 0 5px 10px 10px;">
                                    <a href='NewsView.aspx?ID=<%#Eval("img") %>' style="text-decoration: none;">
                                        <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" Height="111px" ImageUrl="~/images/epica.jpg"
                                            Style="border: 1px solid black;" />
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                                <div style="margin-removed 20px; padding-removed 5px;">
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblContent" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Contect").ToString().Length>150 ? (Eval("Contect") as string).Substring(0,150) : Eval("Contect") %>'></asp:Label>
                                </div>
                                <div style="position: relative; border: 1px solid black; float: left; background-color: #4EAAF5;
                                    margin-left: 3px;">
                                    <a href='NewsView.aspx?ID=<%#Eval("ID") %>' style="color: white; font-size: 15px;
                                        font-weight: bold; text-decoration: none; padding: 4px;">إقرأ المزيد</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div id="Separator" style="width: 600px; height: 2px; border-top: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
                                margin: 5px 17px 5px 5px; clear: both;">
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:DataList>
```

Comment: Isn't your first column in table *News* something like *Id* ?

Comment: See this link

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1318933/c-sharp-int-to-byte

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.Byte[]'.**

As your error already saying that your `Response.BinaryWrite` method is receiving **Int32** type as input which this method is unable to Cast, As above answers by other users, Use column names in query while selecting and `DataReader[0]` is your first column value which i think is **ID** and it's Int32 , So use column name in query as below and use correct column name to fetch correct column value (`DataReader[2]` this will fetch you your image column as per below query).

```
 if (!(this.IsPostBack))
    {
        // For News DataList
        prepareConnection();
        _command.CommandText = "select top (5) ID ,Title,img,Contect from News ORDER BY id DESC";

        _adp = new SqlDataAdapter();
        _tbl = new System.Data.DataTable();
        _adp.SelectCommand = _command;
        _adp.Fill(_tbl);
        SqlDataReader DataReader = _command.ExecuteReader();
        DataReader.Read();
        Response.BinaryWrite((byte[])DataReader[2]);
        DataReader.Close();
        dlNews.DataSource = _tbl;
        dlNews.DataBind();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Alireza mentioned you appear to be using the first value found in the DataReader.

```
Response.BinaryWrite((byte[])DataReader[0]);
```

Is this the correct column number for the `img` column?

If not try changing the `0` value to the correct number for the column and see if you get the error again.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you don't use "SELECT * FROM", instead put the names of the columns you want to use in there instead e.g. "SELECT Column1 FROM ...."

It looks like `DataReader[0]` is an int value not a binary value.

Answer (score -1):

Do:

```
Response.BinaryWrite(DataReader[0] as byte[]);
```

Instead of:

```
Response.BinaryWrite((byte[])DataReader[0]);
```