# Serialport readbyte not getting the right data

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, serial-port

I'm writing a software in VB.net to communicate with an external device with modbus
I have a problem while reading data received from the device , to put it in example , using `sp1.ReadByte()` the data sent from the device is this :

```
05-03-04-00-00-01-9F-FE-0B
```

Update : to read data i used this code

```
Dim reponse As Byte() = New Byte(5 + (2 * nombre_registrre - 1)) {}

        For i As Integer = 0 To response.Length - 1

         response(i) = CByte(genvision.sp1.ReadByte())

        Next
```

but receive this

```
05-03-04-01-9F-FE-0B
```

I want to read it byte by byte  even those 00 00 ,

Thank you so much for your help

Comment: Show us the code you have to ready data from serial port

Comment: I modified my question with the code I used to read data

Comment: Can you try different inputs-outputs and tell us what you get? I personally don't think that the problem is with `00` bytes as you might think

Comment: I tried many times with differents Input-output , the same thing 
the readbyte function seems to ignore 00 :
for example now im trying with : 
05-03-04-00-3A-00-0E-1E-3A
and I'm receiving this :
05-03-04-3A-0E-1E-3A

Comment: How can you be sure that the device is actually sending '00' bytes? Have you tried with any other RS232 terminal to check if it's not a device issue?

Comment: @Jamby
I'm tried also some Modbus simulator , and I get the same result , I can't read the 00 Byte 
is it normal , is this how readbyte works ?

Comment: @Jamby
Using advanced serial port monitor , Im sending Hex string manually , Only NOT &H00 can be read

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved , The problem was : sp1.DiscardNull = true ,

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.discardnull(v=vs.110).aspx

thank you so much for your help

Answer (score 1):

Try :

```
private void serialPort1_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
  byte[] array = new byte[256];
  int i = 0;
  while (serialPort1.BytesToRead > 0)
  {
    array[i]=serialPort1.ReadByte();
    i++;
  }
}
```

**EDIT**
Sorry I was driven here by the `C#` tag! you have to be more exact next times, P.S I'm not sure how to make it in VB but it shouldn't be much different

Comment: Hey , Its okey  , I converted your code to VB.net and tested it , but it gives me the same result ,

Comment: `array[i]=serialPort1.ReadByte();` will give a compile exception `cannot implicitly convert int to byte` - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1318933/c-sharp-int-to-byte for conversion