# c# Encrypt 6 digit number with 128-bit key

Tags: c#, encryption

I have a 6 digit decimal integer whose range is 0 to 999999. I have a 128 bit key. How can I encrypt the number and have a result that is smaller than 8 bytes? I have tried a few samples from MSDN and I end up with a 16 or 8 byte result. Is getting a result with more like 12 digits or fewer possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Convert the decimal into a byte array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1318933/c-sharp-int-to-byte) and xor it with the key. This is essentially a **One-time** pad.

Other than that, basically all stream ciphers can do what you want. For example AES in CTR mode or RC4.

Comment: One-time pad is brilliant and fascinating.

Comment: You really have to keep in mind the *one-time* part of OTP. Although this is not in the name, stream ciphers without a nonce (which blows up the ciphertext and may break your requirement of it being smaller than 8 bytes) have the same problem that the key can be used only once.

Answer (score 0):

use rc4 its output is the same size as its input