# How to convert an integer to binary stored in array

Tags: c#, arrays, binary, type-conversion

I know how to convert an integer from decimal to fixed length binary string:

```
int number = 3;
int toBase = 2;
int length = 8;
Convert.ToString(number, toBase).PadLeft(length, '0')
```

Output:

> 00000011

How to assign the individual elements of that binary string to either `int` (or `bool`) array, such that after the conversion the array will look like<sup>1</sup>:

```
int[] binary = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1}
```

or

```
bool[] binary = {false, false, false, false, false, false, true, true};
```

---

<sup>1. Using the facilities and not trivial `for` loop with `char` to `int` (or `bool`) type conversions.</sup>

Comment: duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1318933/c-sharp-int-to-byte

Comment: `bool[] binary = Convert.ToString(...).Select(c => c == '1').ToArray();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add some *Linq* to represent the `string` as an array:

```
string source = Convert.ToString(number, toBase).PadLeft(length, '0');
```

...

```
int[] binary = source.Select(c => c - '0').ToArray();
```

...

```
bool[] binary = source.Select(c => c == '1').ToArray();
```

Or you can compute arrays directly:

```
int[] binary = Enumerable
  .Range(1, length)
  .Select(i => number / (1 << (length - i)) % 2)
  .ToArray();

bool[] binary = Enumerable
  .Range(1, length)
  .Select(i => number / (1 << (length - i)) % 2 == 1)
  .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you store the string you have created, for example

```
string theBinaryString = Convert.ToString(number, toBase).PadLeft(length, '0');
int[] binary = new int[8];
for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
{
    binary[i] = int.parse(theBinaryString[i].ToString());
}
```

Once the loop has finished you will have the array you are looking for, the `ToString()` is required as selecting from a string as if it was an array returns a char, which cannot be parsed into an int.

Answer (score 1):

maybe like this;

```
"1000110101110".ToCharArray().Select(c => c - '0').ToArray()
```

will give you:

```
int[13] { 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0 }
```

Comment: `48` - magic number which is a *bad parctice*; put `'0'` instead

Comment: when reading your code, it is quite *unclear* what `48` stands for. Put `'0'`, i.e. `c => c - '0'` to make it evident: current character minus `'0'`

Comment: while i kind of get what you are saying I was of the thinking since we are doing programming and the chararray function is being used it should be pretty evident that 48 is an integer being subtracted from c, a character. You can make a edit if you like.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it without converting the number to binary string:

```
var num = 123;
var bits = Enumerable.Range(0, 8).Select(i => (num >> (7-i)) & 1).ToArray();
```

The idea is to shift the number right sequentially by a decreasing number of positions, and mask off all bits except least significant one.

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/hYcUdZ)

Comment: Thank you for the answer! That is for `int` array right?

Comment: @Ziezi Yes, this produces an array of `int`s. If you want an array of `char`s, add a conditional to `Select` expression, or add result to `'0'` to convert an `int` to `char` digit.

Answer (score 0):

```
int[] intArray = stringNumber.ToCharArray().Select(n => Convert.ToInt32(n)).ToArray();
```

Comment: @viveknuna yep I fixed it. My bad