# How to download a video from a website which requires authentication

Tags: download, video-streaming, blob

I want to download recorded lecture videos from my college website which requires authentication. I tried a few ways mentioned below and all failed.

1. Used IDM and got an error saying that `IDM can't download this protected stream.`
2. Used HLS chrome extension which downloads.TS files. These TS files are of a few hundred MB and when opened using VLC or Windows Media Player they show duration `0:00`.
3. Tried GetFLV app and after pasting the URL link, it throws a warning stating that video can't be downloaded.
4. After inspecting the web page I noticed that video has a blob URL. I couldn't get the video downloaded after pasting that URL in jdownloader2.

I couldn't find a working solution.

Comment: Have you tried looking at the .m3u8 files? Do either of them contain EXT-X-KEY tags or EXT-X-SESSION-KEY tags, if so, the stream might have DRM which makes it useless without the appropriate key.

Comment: @colde I found these lines `#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:0
#EXT-X-ALLOW-CACHE:YES
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:12
#EXT-X-KEY:METHOD=AES-128` How to deal with this?

Comment: In that case, you are dealing with encrypted HLS. You can try and see if EXT-X-KEY has a URL where you can fetch the key. If not, it might be a bit tricky. You might also want to look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50628791/decrypt-m3u8-playlist-encrypted-with-aes-128-without-iv