# C# - Converting uint to byte[]

Tags: c#, arrays

So I was using BitConverter.GetBytes() to convert uint32 to byte[], but my the order in the array seems to be backwards.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1184xdy4.aspx
(shows that it's byte[] seems to be little endian).

Is there a better way handle this than just using linq to reverse the byte arrays?

Comment: I guess that's where I'm confused though since BitConverter.IsLittleEndian returns false, but BitConverter.GetBytes() returns little endian arrays.

Comment: If this is Windows, BitConverter.IsLittleEndian returning false is clearly a bug, since x86 and x86-64 processors are Little Endian.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I figured out a big part of my confusion is related to this: [IsLittleEndian field reports false, but it must be Little-Endian?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2023672/islittleendian-field-reports-false-but-it-must-be-little-endian)

What I ended up doing was wrapping all the BitConverter calls with call that took an extra parameter to specifiy endianness, then added a function that gets called to check to see if the bytes need to be revered.

```
public static class BitEndianConverter
{
    public static byte[] GetBytes(bool value, bool littleEndian)
    {
        return ReverseAsNeeded(BitConverter.GetBytes(value), littleEndian);
    }

    public static byte[] GetBytes(char value, bool littleEndian)
    {
        return ReverseAsNeeded(BitConverter.GetBytes(value), littleEndian);
    }
    public static byte[] GetBytes(double value, bool littleEndian)
    {
        return ReverseAsNeeded(BitConverter.GetBytes(value), littleEndian);
    }
    public static byte[] GetBytes(float value, bool littleEndian)
    {
        return ReverseAsNeeded(BitConverter.GetBytes(value), littleEndian);
    }
    public static byte[] GetBytes(int value, bool littleEndian)
    {
        return ReverseAsNeeded(BitConverter.GetBytes(value), littleEndian);
    }
    public static byte[] GetBytes(long value, bool littleEndian)
    {
        return ReverseAsNeeded(BitConverter.GetBytes(value), littleEndian);
    }
    public static byte[] GetBytes(short value, bool littleEndian)
    {
        return ReverseAsNeeded(BitConverter.GetBytes(value), littleEndian);
    }
    public static byte[] GetBytes(uint value, bool littleEndian)
    {
        return ReverseAsNeeded(BitConverter.GetBytes(value), littleEndian);
    }
    public static byte[] GetBytes(ulong value, bool littleEndian)
    {
        return ReverseAsNeeded(BitConverter.GetBytes(value), littleEndian);
    }
    public static byte[] GetBytes(ushort value, bool littleEndian)
    {
        return ReverseAsNeeded(BitConverter.GetBytes(value), littleEndian);
    }

    private static byte[] ReverseAsNeeded(byte[] bytes, bool wantsLittleEndian)
    {
        if (wantsLittleEndian == BitConverter.IsLittleEndian)
            return bytes;
        else
            return (byte[])bytes.Reverse().ToArray();
    }
}
```

Comment: I copied this class, it works well and is more intuitive and readable than other solutions.  I was wondering if it makes sense or if it is possible  to make GetBytes generic ?  something like public static byte[] GetBytes<T>(T value, bool littleEndian)...

Answer (score 7):

`Array.Reverse` to change the endianess.

Answer (score 6):

If you are going to be moving between platform architectures simply reversing the array might be correct on one platform, but fail on a platform that is already using big endian.

You use the [IPAddress.HostToNetworkOrder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ipaddress.hosttonetworkorder.aspx) functions, which will ensure that the data is always in network order (big endian).

```
uint number = 234234233;
uint bigEndian = (uint)IPAddress.HostToNetworkOrder((int)number);
byte[] b = BitConverter.GetBytes(bigEndian);
```

Comment: Thank you. It is faster than Array.Reverse. But I had troubles with types while not wrote code like this: var buffer = BitConverter.GetBytes((uint)IPAddress.HostToNetworkOrder((int)i));

Comment: @Geograph, what trouble did you have? It might be worth creating a dedicated question for this, that way you can provide a more complete example and details.

Comment: Your original example can't compile with error "CS0266 Cannot implicitly convert type 'long' to 'uint'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)"

Comment: @Geograph, I see. Yes for this to work correctly you would need to cast number to int, to get a int sized result back. I will update the sample, thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Microsoft discusses the little-endian / big-endian issue with the GetBytes() method on the documentation page for [BitConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Following is a method to always get big endian byte array quickly.

```
    public static byte[] GetBigEndianBytes(UInt32 val, bool isLittleEndian)
    {
        UInt32 bigEndian = val;
        if (isLittleEndian)
        {
            bigEndian = (val & 0x000000FFU) << 24 | (val & 0x0000FF00U) << 8 |
                 (val & 0x00FF0000U) >> 8 | (val & 0xFF000000U) >> 24;
        }
        return BitConverter.GetBytes(bigEndian);
    }
```

This overload can be handy, although *care must be taken when working across machines with different endian-nesses*.

```
    public static byte[] GetBigEndianBytes(UInt32 val)
    {
        return GetBigEndianBytes(val, BitConverter.IsLittleEndian);
    }
```