# Converting a big endian array to an Int64

Tags: c#, .net, mono, bitconverter

Im using a System.IO.BinaryReader to read a data from a serialized file. The file is big endian. So what I did to read the Int64 (long) from the stream was read 8 bytes from it. What I need to do is convert those 8 bytes of big endian into little endian long representation.

I can't use System.BitConverter as it will be compiled with Mono for use on Linux which could be running on big endian and with Visual Studio for Windows which is little endian.

Comment: What of it? Mono implements `System.BitConverter` as well – of course.

Comment: I read [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2021679/1350209) that "BitConverter.ToInt64 is suppose to respect the endianness of your underlying machine."

Comment: long value = Convert.ToInt64(binaryReader.ReadBytes(8).Reverse());  Skeet did something with big-endian, check his blog.

Comment: Convert.ToInt* does not take a byte array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `System.Net.IPAddress.NetworkToHostOrder` or `System.Net.IPAddress.HostToNetworkOrder`

For ex,
`System.Net.IPAddress.HostToNetworkOrder(0x0123456789abcdefl)` would return `efcdab8967452301`

Comment: Don't forget that the machine you are on might be big endian in the first place. You can check by using BitConverter.IsLittleEndian http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.islittleendian.aspx .

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to end up using Mono anyway, you can use [DataConvert](http://www.mono-project.com/Mono_DataConvert).

Works fine on Windows too. I'm using it in one of my projects.

Comment: Even on regular .NET, I would say. DataConvert's Python/Perl-like pack/unpack functions are pleasure to use.

Answer (score 1):

John Skeet's [miscutil](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/miscutil/) library implements a BigEndianBitConverter.

Comment: I opened up his library and discovered he uses `Operator<T>` in GenericMath. Never knew about this... I could have used it many times. Very cool!