# BitArray stores bits in reverse order when initialized with an Int32 array

Tags: c#, endianness, bitarray

Best way to describe my miss understanding is with the code itself:

```
var emptyByteArray = new byte[2];

var specificByteArray = new byte[] {150, 105}; //0x96 = 150, 0x69 = 105
var bitArray1 = new BitArray(specificByteArray);
bitArray1.CopyTo(emptyByteArray, 0); //[0]: 150, [1]:105

var hexString = "9669";
var intValueForHex = Convert.ToInt32(hexString, 16); //16 indicates to convert from hex
var bitArray2 = new BitArray(new[] {intValueForHex}) {Length = 16}; //Length=16 truncates the BitArray

bitArray2.CopyTo(emptyByteArray, 0); //[0]:105, [1]:150 (inversed, why??)
```

I've been reading that the bitarray iterates from the LSB to the MSB, what's the best way for me to initialize the bitarray starting from a hex string then?

Comment: in the hex `0x9669`, 69 is the least significant byte and should appear first in any bit or byte array.  Copy it to an int array and you'll get one element, `0x9669`.

Comment: I asked a related question a while back:   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2003380/net-reversing-byte-order

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you are thinking about it wrong.  Why are you even using a BitArray?  Endianness is a *byte-related* convention, BitArray is just an array of bits.  Since it is least-significant bit first, the correct way to store a 32-bit number in a bit array is with bit 0 at index 0 and bit 31 at index 31.  This isn't just just my personal bias towards little-endianness (bit 0 should be in byte 0 not byte 3 for goodness sake), it's because BitArray stores bit 0 of a byte at index 0 in the array.  It also stores bit 0 of a 32-bit integer in bit 0 of the array, no matter the endianness of the platform you are on.

For example, instead of your integer 9669, let's look at 1234.  No matter what platform you are on, that 16-bit number has the following bit representation, because we write a hex number with the most significant hex digit `1` to the left and the least significant hex digit `4` to the right, bit 0 is on the right (a human convention):

```
  1    2    3    4
0001 0010 0011 0100
```

No matter how an architecture orders the bytes, bit 0 of a 16-bit number always means the least-significant bit (the right-most here) and bit 15 means the most-significant bit (the left-most here).  Due to this, your bit array will always be like this, with bit 0 on the left because that's the way I read an array (with index 0 being bit 0 and index 15 being bit 15):

```
---4--- ---3--- ---2--- ---1---
0 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0
```

What you are doing is trying to impose the byte order you want onto an array of bits where it doesn't belong.  If you want to reverse the bytes, then you'll get this in the bit array which makes a lot less sense, and means you'll have to reverse the bytes again when you get the integer back out:

```
---2--- ---1--- ---4--- ---3---
0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 0
```

I don't think this makes any kind of sense for storing an integer.  If you want to store the big-endian representation of a 32-bit number in the BitArray then what you are really storing is a byte array that just happens to be the big-endian representation of a 32-bit number and you should convert to a byte array first make it big-endian if necessary before putting it in the BitArray:

```
int number = 0x1234;
byte[] bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(number);
if (BitConverter.IsLittleEndian)
{
    bytes = bytes.Reverse().ToArray();
}
BitArray ba = new BitArray(bytes);
```