# For BitConverter To Use Big Endian

Tags: .net, vb.net, endianness

I am trying to use BitConverter to convert byte arrays to Integers so I can perform bitwise operations on the entire array. However, it appears my machine deals with bytes as little endian, but I have some static values that are in big endian.

I am able to deal with it by reversing the arrays if `BitConverter.IsLittleEndian`, but I'm wondering if there is a way to force the BitConverter class to use a specific endianess instead (without creating my own class, I'm looking for an existing method).

What I'm doing now:

```
Dim MyBytes() as Byte = New Byte() { 0, 0, 0, 1 }
Dim MyBytesAsInteger as Integer
If BitConverter.IsLittleEndian Then
    MyBytesAsInteger = BitConverter.ToInt32(MyBytes.Reverse.ToArray, 0)
Else
    MyBytesAsInteger = BitConverter.ToInt32(MyBytes, 0)
End If
```

Comment: `but I'm wondering if there is a way` - probably not, as `BitConverter` appears to be designed to [respect the endiannes of the current machine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2021679/11683), but there are [workarounds](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8241060/11683).

Comment: you know you are creating a byte array not bit array. 1 byte=8 bits so you have an array of 4 integer of 8 bit and not an array of 4 bits

Comment: @MutedDisk : The OP never implied that he was dealing with bits? Note that the [**`BitConverter` class**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter(v=vs.110).aspx) doesn't actually work with bits, but with bytes. So it's Microsoft that has given the class an incorrect name. :p

Answer (score 3):

I've just found a piece of code that can handle Big/Little endian conversions, made by Jon Skeet.

https://jonskeet.uk/csharp/miscutil/ (download the sources from here)

His library has many utility functions. For Big/Little endian conversions you can check the `MiscUtil/Conversion/EndianBitConverter.cs` file.

```
var littleEndianBitConverter = new MiscUtil.Conversion.LittleEndianBitConverter();
littleEndianBitConverter.ToInt64(bytes, offset);

var bigEndianBitConverter = new MiscUtil.Conversion.BigEndianBitConverter();
bigEndianBitConverter.ToInt64(bytes, offset);
```

His software is from 2009 but I guess it's still relevant.