# How to take a collection of bytes and pull typed values out of it?

Tags: .net, interop, binary, legacy

Say I have a collection of bytes

```
var bytes = new byte[] {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7};
```

and I want to pull out a defined value from the bytes as a managed type, e.g. a `ushort`. What is a simple way to define what types reside at what location in the collection and pull out those values?

One (ugly) way is to use `System.BitConverter` and a `Queue` or `byte[]` with an index and simply iterate through, e.g.:

```
int index = 0;
ushort first = System.BitConverter.ToUint16(bytes, index);
index += 2; // size of a ushort
int second = System.BitConverter.ToInt32(bytes, index);
index += 4;
...
```

This method gets very, very tedious when you deal with a lot of these structures!

I know that there is the `System.Runtime.InteropServices.StructLayoutAttribute` which allows me to define the locations of types inside a struct or class, but there doesn't seem to be a way to import the collection of bytes into that struct. If I could somehow overlay the struct on the collection of bytes and pull out the values, that would be ideal. E.g.

```
Foo foo = (Foo)bytes; // doesn't work because I'd need to implement the implicit operator
ushort first = foo.first;
int second = foo.second;
...
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, Size=FOO_SIZE)]
public struct Foo  {
    [FieldOffset(0)] public ushort first;
    [FieldOffset(2)] public int second;
}
```

Any thoughts on how to achieve this?

[EDIT: See also my [question on how to deal with the bytes when they are big endian](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2480116/marshalling-a-big-endian-byte-collection-into-a-struct-in-order-to-pull-out-value).]

Comment: Are all the types you are interested integral (or "fixed" arrays of integrals)?

Comment: @gooch: No, but we could settle for that and write helper methods for when we have strings.

Comment: Ok, this works quite well for integral types. Its a bit cumbersome for arrays of these types, as they need to be designated "fixed" (which essentially mean it is a pointer to the beginning of memory). We have not been able to achieve other types, but there is a way to specify Size for each field, this gets hairy quickly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have done this quite a bit as we talk directly to hardware via bytes over serial.

Given the struct definition

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, Size=FOO_SIZE)]
public struct Foo  {
    [FieldOffset(0)] public ushort first;
    [FieldOffset(2)] public int second;
}
```

You can use a class like this to perform the conversion

```
public class ByteArrayToStruct<StructType>
{
    public StructType ConvertToStruct(int size, byte[] thebuffer)
    {
        try
        {
            int theSize = size;
            IntPtr ptr1 = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(theSize);
            Marshal.Copy(thebuffer, 0, ptr1, theSize);
            StructType theStruct = (StructType)Marshal.PtrToStructure(ptr1, typeof(StructType));
            Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptr1);
            return theStruct;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return default(StructType);
        }
    }
}
```

Conversely, you could also create List from the array and do something like the following:

```
ushort first = BitConverter.ToInt16(myList.ToArray(), 0);
myList.RemoveRange(0, sizeof(ushort));
[...]
```

This would essentially be keeping the relevant data at the "head" of the list, so you wont have to keep track of the position in the array.

Comment: Nice! That's what I was looking for, at least from my preliminary tests.

Comment: Oh no, it only works for little-endian bytes (since my host machine is little endian)! Do you have a workaround for taking in big-endian bytes? Note, it is not sufficient to reverse the whole byte array, since it is each value that has swapped endianness: e.g. from `{1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0}`, you could pull out a `ushort` of `1` and `uint` of `2`, but reversing the bytes would give you a `ushort` of `0` and a `uint` of `0x00020001` or `131073`.

Comment: Basically, I need the struct to act as though it were big-endian when it receives the bytes, then to allow me to get the values out of it as though it were the normal endianness of .NET managed code.

Comment: I see what you mean. If you are not opposed to using a 3rd party library, I found this SO post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/217980/c-little-endian-or-big-endian)

Comment: I am not opposed to using a library, but Jon's code does not address how to make the struct act as big endian. His code simply adds big-endian functions to System.BitConverter (which I have already done in my own library [too bad I couldn't find Jon's MiscUtil class before now!]). Thanks for searching, though.

Comment: Well, I'll give you the credit, @gooch, since you answered my question for the little-endian case and provided the keywords I needed to continue searching. Thanks!

Comment: I am sorry that the solution did not satisfy your needs. This is a relatively painless way to stuff bytes into structs. Unfortunately, we have not worked with the Big-Endian -> Little-Endian scenario. That sounds especially tricky as each value needs to be swapped (cannot run a blanket swap).

Answer (score 0):

do it the first way. define a Buffer class that has the data bytes and a cursor. THen define methods like getInt16, getInt32 etc. Then you go

```
  Buffer b(bytes);
  ushort a = b.getInt16();
  int x = b.getInt32();
```

I have this in my utils bag. I also have the opposite, to make a buffer out of ints strings,....