# Marshal.PtrToStructure (and back again) and generic solution for endianness swapping

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, marshalling, endianness

I have a system where a remote agent sends serialized structures (from an embedded C system) for me to read and store via IP/UDP. In some cases I need to send back the same structure types. I thought I had a nice setup using Marshal.PtrToStructure (receive) and Marshal.StructureToPtr (send). However, a small gotcha is that the network big endian integers need to be converted to my x86 little endian format to be used locally. When I'm sending them off again, big endian is the way to go.

Here are the functions in question:

```
    private static T BytesToStruct<T>(ref byte[] rawData) where T: struct
    {
        T result = default(T);
        GCHandle handle = GCHandle.Alloc(rawData, GCHandleType.Pinned);
        try
        {
            IntPtr rawDataPtr = handle.AddrOfPinnedObject();
            result = (T)Marshal.PtrToStructure(rawDataPtr, typeof(T));
        }
        finally
        {
            handle.Free();
        }
        return result;
    }

    private static byte[] StructToBytes<T>(T data) where T: struct
    {
        byte[] rawData = new byte[Marshal.SizeOf(data)];
        GCHandle handle = GCHandle.Alloc(rawData, GCHandleType.Pinned);
        try
        {
            IntPtr rawDataPtr = handle.AddrOfPinnedObject();
            Marshal.StructureToPtr(data, rawDataPtr, false);
        }
        finally
        {
            handle.Free();
        }
        return rawData;
    }
```

And a quick example structure that might be used like this:

```
byte[] data = this.sock.Receive(ref this.ipep);
Request request = BytesToStruct<Request>(ref data);
```

Where the structure in question looks like:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, Pack = 1)]
private struct Request
{
    public byte type;
    public short sequence;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 5)]
    public byte[] address;
}
```

What (generic) way can I swap the endianness when marshalling the structures? My need is such that the locally stored 'request.sequence' in this example should be little-endian for displaying to the user. I don't want to have to swap the endianness in a structure-specific way since it's a generic problem.

My first thought was to use Reflection, but I'm not very familiar with that feature. Also, I hoped that there would be a better solution out there that somebody could point me towards. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: How did it take two years for someone to point out that we're asking the same qeuestion (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2480116/marshalling-a-big-endian-byte-collection-into-a-struct-in-order-to-pull-out-valu)!? :-)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Reflection does seem like the only real way to accomplish what you're after.

I've put together some code below. It creates an attribute called `EndianAttribute` that can be applied at the field level on a struct. I've included the definition for this attribute and it's associated enum, as well as the modifications to your code necessary to use it.

As a side note, you did not need to define `rawData` as a `ref` parameter.

Note that this does require the use of C# 3.0/.NET 3.5, since I'm using LINQ and anonymous types in the function doing the work. It would not be difficult to rewrite the function without these features, though.

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Field)]
public class EndianAttribute : Attribute
{
    public Endianness Endianness { get; private set; }

    public EndianAttribute(Endianness endianness)
    {
        this.Endianness = endianness;
    }
}

public enum Endianness
{
    BigEndian,
    LittleEndian
}

private static void RespectEndianness(Type type, byte[] data)
{
    var fields = type.GetFields().Where(f => f.IsDefined(typeof(EndianAttribute), false))
        .Select(f => new
        {
            Field = f,
            Attribute = (EndianAttribute)f.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(EndianAttribute), false)[0],
            Offset = Marshal.OffsetOf(type, f.Name).ToInt32()
        }).ToList();

    foreach (var field in fields)
    {
        if ((field.Attribute.Endianness == Endianness.BigEndian && BitConverter.IsLittleEndian) ||
            (field.Attribute.Endianness == Endianness.LittleEndian && !BitConverter.IsLittleEndian))
        {
            Array.Reverse(data, field.Offset, Marshal.SizeOf(field.Field.FieldType));
        }
    }
}

private static T BytesToStruct<T>(byte[] rawData) where T : struct
{
    T result = default(T);

    RespectEndianness(typeof(T), rawData);     

    GCHandle handle = GCHandle.Alloc(rawData, GCHandleType.Pinned);

    try
    {
        IntPtr rawDataPtr = handle.AddrOfPinnedObject();
        result = (T)Marshal.PtrToStructure(rawDataPtr, typeof(T));
    }
    finally
    {
        handle.Free();
    }        

    return result;
}

private static byte[] StructToBytes<T>(T data) where T : struct
{
    byte[] rawData = new byte[Marshal.SizeOf(data)];
    GCHandle handle = GCHandle.Alloc(rawData, GCHandleType.Pinned);
    try
    {
        IntPtr rawDataPtr = handle.AddrOfPinnedObject();
        Marshal.StructureToPtr(data, rawDataPtr, false);
    }
    finally
    {
        handle.Free();
    }

    RespectEndianness(typeof(T), rawData);     

    return rawData;
}
```

Comment: Just the slick kind of setup I was looking for. I'll give this a shot.

Comment: Works so far without any other modifications... I like this solution a lot.

Comment: Great solution!  If you don't like the performance hit of walking through the reflection every time you convert, then you could use ILGenerator to dyamically generate (and cache) a "converter" class for each of your structs.  It may sound complicated, but there's a nice little example here: http://varjabedian.net/archive/2008/07/29/casting-a-byte-array-into-structures-in-c.aspx

Comment: Nice solution. Still some typos in the enum and the attribute ctor.

Comment: This works really well when you make BytesToStruct and StructToBytes extensions of a stream.

Answer (score 2):

For those of us without Linq, a replacement `RespectEndianness()`:

```
private static void RespectEndianness(Type type, byte[] data) {
    foreach (FieldInfo f in type.GetFields()) {
        if (f.IsDefined(typeof(EndianAttribute), false)) {
            EndianAttribute att = (EndianAttribute)f.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(EndianAttribute), false)[0];
            int offset = Marshal.OffsetOf(type, f.Name).ToInt32();
            if ((att.Endianness == Endianness.BigEndian && BitConverter.IsLittleEndian) ||
                (att.Endianness == Endianness.LittleEndian && !BitConverter.IsLittleEndian)) {
                Array.Reverse(data, offset, Marshal.SizeOf(f.FieldType));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's my variation - it handles nested structs and arrays, with the assumption that arrays are of a fixed size, eg marked with a [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = N)] attribute.

```
public static class Serializer
{
    public static byte[] GetBytes<T>(T structure, bool respectEndianness = true) where T : struct
    {
        var size = Marshal.SizeOf(structure); //or Marshal.SizeOf<T>(); in .net 4.5.1
        var bytes = new byte[size];
        var ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(size);

        Marshal.StructureToPtr(structure, ptr, true);
        Marshal.Copy(ptr, bytes, 0, size);
        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptr);

        if (respectEndianness) RespectEndianness(typeof(T), bytes);  

        return bytes;
    }

    public static T FromBytes<T>(byte[] bytes, bool respectEndianness = true) where T : struct
    {
        var structure = new T();

        if (respectEndianness) RespectEndianness(typeof(T), bytes);    

        int size = Marshal.SizeOf(structure);  //or Marshal.SizeOf<T>(); in .net 4.5.1
        IntPtr ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(size);

        Marshal.Copy(bytes, 0, ptr, size);

        structure = (T)Marshal.PtrToStructure(ptr, structure.GetType());
        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptr);

        return structure;
    }

    private static void RespectEndianness(Type type, byte[] data, int offSet = 0)
    {
        var fields = type.GetFields()
            .Select(f => new
            {
                Field = f,
                Offset = Marshal.OffsetOf(type, f.Name).ToInt32(),
            }).ToList();

        foreach (var field in fields)
        {
            if (field.Field.FieldType.IsArray)
            {
                //handle arrays, assuming fixed length
                var attr = field.Field.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(MarshalAsAttribute), false).FirstOrDefault();
                var marshalAsAttribute = attr as MarshalAsAttribute;
                if (marshalAsAttribute == null || marshalAsAttribute.SizeConst == 0)
                    throw new NotSupportedException(
                        "Array fields must be decorated with a MarshalAsAttribute with SizeConst specified.");

                var arrayLength = marshalAsAttribute.SizeConst;
                var elementType = field.Field.FieldType.GetElementType();
                var elementSize = Marshal.SizeOf(elementType);
                var arrayOffset = field.Offset + offSet;

                for (int i = arrayOffset; i < arrayOffset + elementSize * arrayLength; i += elementSize)                    {
                    RespectEndianness(elementType, data, i);
                }
            }
            else if (!field.Field.FieldType.IsPrimitive) //or !field.Field.FiledType.GetFields().Length == 0
            {
                //handle nested structs
                RespectEndianness(field.Field.FieldType, data, field.Offset);
            }
            else
            {
                //handle primitive types
                Array.Reverse(data, offSet + field.Offset, Marshal.SizeOf(field.Field.FieldType));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Since .NET 4.5.1 you can use `var size = Marshal.SizeOf<T>();` instead of `var size = Marshal.SizeOf(structure);`.

Comment: I just came across your code and I think it's pretty good, except for a little error in your recursion where you handle arrays. I added "var arrayOffset = field.Offset + offSet;" and "for (int i = arrayOffset; i < arrayOffset + elementSize * arrayLength; i += elementSize)". Thanks for posting.

Answer (score 0):

This question was awesome and helped me a lot! I needed to expand on the endian changer though as it doesn't seem to handle arrays or structs within structs.

```
    public struct mytest
    {
        public int myint;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 10)]
        public int[] ptime;
    }

    public static void SwapIt(Type type, byte[] recvbyte, int offset)
    {
        foreach (System.Reflection.FieldInfo fi in type.GetFields())
        {
            int index = Marshal.OffsetOf(type, fi.Name).ToInt32() + offset;
            if (fi.FieldType == typeof(int))
            {
                Array.Reverse(recvbyte, index, sizeof(int));
            }
            else if (fi.FieldType == typeof(float))
            {
                Array.Reverse(recvbyte, index, sizeof(float));
            }
            else if (fi.FieldType == typeof(double))
            {
                Array.Reverse(recvbyte, index, sizeof(double));
            }
            else
            {
                // Maybe we have an array
                if (fi.FieldType.IsArray)
                {
                    // Check for MarshalAs attribute to get array size
                    object[] ca = fi.GetCustomAttributes(false);
                    if (ca.Count() > 0 && ca[0] is MarshalAsAttribute)
                    {
                        int size = ((MarshalAsAttribute)ca[0]).SizeConst;
                        // Need to use GetElementType to see that int[] is made of ints
                        if (fi.FieldType.GetElementType() == typeof(int))
                        {
                            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
                            {
                                Array.Reverse(recvbyte, index + (i * sizeof(int)), sizeof(int));
                            }
                        }
                        else if (fi.FieldType.GetElementType() == typeof(float))
                        {
                            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
                            {
                                Array.Reverse(recvbyte, index + (i * sizeof(float)), sizeof(float));
                            }
                        }
                        else if (fi.FieldType.GetElementType() == typeof(double))
                        {
                            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
                            {
                                Array.Reverse(recvbyte, index + (i * sizeof(double)), sizeof(double));
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            // An array of something else?
                            Type t = fi.FieldType.GetElementType();
                            int s = Marshal.SizeOf(t);
                            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
                            {
                                SwapIt(t, recvbyte, index + (i * s));
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    SwapIt(fi.FieldType, recvbyte, index);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Note this code was only tested on structs made of int, float, double. Will probably mess up if you have a string in there!