# Alignment of data on the end side of space in Marshal

Tags: c#, structure, marshalling, padding

I have the flollowing structure:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct mystructure
{
    public Byte fieldA;
    public Byte fieldB;
    public UInt16 fieldC;
    public UInt32 fieldD;
}
```

Then, filling with data:

```
var obj = new mystructure()
{
    fieldA = 4
    ,
    fieldB = 0
    ,
    fieldC = 16
    ,
    fieldD = 9
};
```

And marshaling:

```
Int32 objsize = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(mystructure));
Byte[] ret = new Byte[objsize];
IntPtr buff = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(objsize);
Marshal.StructureToPtr(obj, buff, true);
Marshal.Copy(buff, ret, 0, objsize);
Marshal.FreeHGlobal(buff);
```

I got this data layout in my `ret` variable:

```
[0]: 4
[1]: 0
[2]: 16
[3]: 0
[4]: 9
[5]: 0
[6]: 0
[7]: 0
```

All data are aligned at the beginning of your space, how do I align on the end? Note that it is different from using the `[FieldOffset]` atribute.
I need the following result:

```
[0]: 4
[1]: 0
[2]: 0
[3]: 16
[4]: 0
[5]: 0
[6]: 0
[7]: 9
```

**UPDATED - My solution**

```
public static void LittleEndianToBigEndian<T>(Byte[] data, Int32 startOffset = 0) where T : struct
{
    LittleEndianToBigEndian(typeof(T), data, startOffset);
}

public static void LittleEndianToBigEndian(Type structType, Byte[] data, Int32 startOffset = 0)
{
    if (!structType.IsValueType || structType.IsEnum || structType.IsPrimitive)
        throw new ArgumentException("The conversion only supports struct types", "structType");

    var validFieldsRule = new Func<FieldInfo, Boolean>(f =>
        !f.IsStatic &&
        f.FieldType != typeof(String) &&
        f.FieldType != typeof(Byte) &&
        f.FieldType != typeof(SByte) &&
        (f.FieldType.IsArray || f.FieldType.IsValueType)
    );

    foreach (var field in structType.GetFields().Where(validFieldsRule))
    {
        var offset = Marshal.OffsetOf(structType, field.Name).ToInt32();
        var effectiveOffset = startOffset + offset;

        if (field.FieldType.GetFields().Any(validFieldsRule) && !field.FieldType.IsEnum)
        {
            LittleEndianToBigEndian(field.FieldType, data, effectiveOffset);
        }
        else if (field.FieldType.IsArray)
        {
            //to-do: deal with arrays!
        }
        else
        {
            Array.Reverse
                (
                    data
                    ,
                    effectiveOffset
                    ,
                    Marshal.SizeOf
                        (
                            field.FieldType.IsEnum ?
                                Enum.GetUnderlyingType(field.FieldType)
                                    :
                                field.FieldType
                        )
                );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "align on the end".  Do you want big-endian (16,0) for UInt16?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2623761/marshal-ptrtostructure-and-back-again-and-generic-solution-for-endianness-swap/2624377#2624377  has a very general solution for your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is about byte order not alignment.  Byte order or [endianness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) is about the weither or not he most-significant byte is first or last.

`Marshal.StructurePtr` uses the byte order of the underlaying CPU because it assumes you want to call an unmanaged function.

This may help you [Marshalling a big-endian byte collection into a struct in order to pull out values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2480116/marshalling-a-big-endian-byte-collection-into-a-struct-in-order-to-pull-out-valu)

Basically you will have to create the byte array by hand.  big endian is also known as `network byte order`.  You can use [ipaddress.hosttonetworkorder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ipaddress.hosttonetworkorder(v=vs.110).aspx) to get the correct format for ints and longs.

Comment: I didn't know this endianness thing. Thanks a lot!