# NETFLOW PACKET VERSION 5 convert byte 24-27 to datetime

Tags: network-programming, traffic, netflow

i have a plan to gather netflow packets(v5) come from a mikrotik router in c# app, i open a udp listener on the port which packets come and read the byte array, i split the packet byte array by looking at packet format [caligare.com](http://netflow.caligare.com/netflow_v5.htm), as the packet format byte 24-27 is the "SysUptime at start of flow" , now i want to convert this 4 byte to datetime.

for example this 4 byte is 134 , 88, 157, 126
how should i do that?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These 4 bytes are basically a 32-bit integer. What you must be aware of while working with network-transmitted packets is byte order, or [Endianness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness). In network-transmitted packets, these are ordered as big-endian, while Intel x86 architecture is little-endian. This means that bytes in the packet are in the opposite order to how the machine stores them.

This question has answers how to convert network-order (big-endian) bytes into host-order (little-endian on x86) bytes: [C# little endian or big endian?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217980/c-sharp-little-endian-or-big-endian) You will need to convert the byte array that you have into an Int32 value in order to use `IPAddress.NetworkToHost` method:

```
using System;
using System.Net;

int netSysUptimeAtStart = BitConverter.ToInt32(uptimeStartArray, 0)
int sysUptimeAtStart = IPAddress.NetworkToHostOrder(netSysUptimeAtStart)
```

Once you get the correct integer, you need to convert it to `TimeSpan` (not `DateTime` as you're asking). The reason is that the "system uptime at start of flow" is not really a point in time, but rather a time span.

You need to find out which measure is used for uptime -- is it microseconds? seconds? Using that information, you can construct a correct TimeSpan using this:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.timespan(v=vs.90).aspx