# How to convert a Buffer to an array of ints node.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, buffer

I have a c# application that converts a double array to a byte array of data to a node.js server which is converted to a Buffer (as convention seems to recommend). I want to convert this buffer into an array of the numbers originally stored in the double array, I've had a look at other questions but they either aren't applicable or just don't work ([...buf], Array.prototype.slice.call(buf, 0) etc.).

Essentially I have a var buf which contains the data, I want this to be an array of integers, is there any way I can do this?

Thank you.

Comment: take a look at parseInt() in javascript -
 https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp

Comment: @RishikeshDhokare can I just apply that straight to the buffer??

Comment: You cant access a buffer directly. You need to use a "view" on it, usually a `TypedArray`

Comment: As nodejs' `Buffer` already is a `Uint8Array`, you can work with it like a normal array to get the integers

Comment: @JonasW. okay so I can just iterate through it and parse the ints from it into a new array?

Comment: Just use it like in array. Theres no need to parse or anything (if the integers are 8 bits long and unsigned)

Comment: w3schools is not a good resource and parseInt has nothing to do with binary data, it parses strings to int. JonasW has the right idea.

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to know WHAT numbers are in the array. I'll assume they are 32bit integers. So first, create encapsulating Typed Array around the buffer:

```
 // @type {ArrayBuffer}
 var myBuffer = // get the bufffer from C#
 // Interprets byte array as 32 bit int array
 var myTypedArray = new Int32Array(myBuffer);
 // And if you really want standard JS array:
 var normalArray = [];
 // Push all numbers from buffer to Array
 normalArray.push.apply(normalArray, myTypedArray);
```

Note that stuff might get more complicated if the C#'s array is in Big Endian, but I assume it's not. According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/217993/607407), you should be fine.

Comment: Int32Array doesn't seem to be working for me, do you know how I can find what type they are? Thanks

Comment: Can you look into the C# application source code? Or you can use trial end error - on MDN you can find list of typed array classes, just try every each of them.

Comment: I've tried each and every data type, I am expecting 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 however I get 0,0,0,0,0,0,240,63,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,64,0,0,0,0,0,0,8,64,0,0,0,0,0,0,16,64,0,0,0,0,0,0,20,64 for each datatype (except Int8Array which replaces the 240 with -16) when I print the array out toString, any ideas why?

Comment: Can you provide me with the array in it's binary form? Or as a list of bytes? Or maybe with the code of the C# application? I can't help you without knowing the data format.

Comment: C#: double[] post = new double[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5} is how the array is formed, it's then converted into a byte[] array with byte[] postArray = new byte[post.Length * 8] then Buffer.BlockCopy(post, 0, postArray, 0, postArray.Length), this is then sent to the node.js server with a webclient

Comment: inside node.js it's formed into a buffer with 
req.on('data', function(data){
   var buf = new Buffer(0);
   buf = Buffer.concat([buf, data]);
etc..

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do this with a DataView and used that to iterate over the buffer, something I'd tried before but for some reason didn't work but does now.